# How to call Firebase Cloud Functions from Angular and AngularFire?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I'm trying to understand the [AngularFireFunctions](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md) documentation. I made a new Angular project and a new Firestore database, installed AngularFire and Firebase, hooked up the Firebase credentials to `environments.ts`, and initialized `firebase-functions`, `firebase-admin`, and `firestore`.

I fixed a bug in `functions/package.json`. The initialization program creates this line:

```js
"main": "lib/index.js",
```

which should be

```js
"main": "src/index.ts",
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
myproject
 +- .firebaserc    # Hidden file that helps you quickly switch between
 |                 # projects with `firebase use`
 |
 +- firebase.json  # Describes properties for your project
 |
 +- functions/     # Directory containing all your functions code
      |
      +- node_modules/ # directory where your dependencies (declared in # package.json) are installed
      |
      +- package-lock.json
      |
      +- src/
          |
           +- index.js  # main source file for your Cloud Functions code
      |
      +- tsconfig.json  # if you chose TypeScript
      |
      +- package.json  # npm package file describing your Cloud Functions code
```

I spun up a new Angular project and set up `app.module.ts` exactly as the [AngularFireFunctions](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md) documentation recommends:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule, USE_EMULATOR } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireFunctionsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: USE_EMULATOR, useValue: ['localhost', 5001] }
   ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I made a button in my HTML view to call the Firebase Cloud Function:

```html
<div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="basic" (click)='callMe()'>Call me!</button>
</div>
```

I imported `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin` into `index.ts` as the documentation recommends. Then I uncommented the default function that comes with `index.ts` and added a `console.log`.

```js
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and set up triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log("Hello world!")
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Finally we get to `app.component.ts`. I don't understand the provided code in the documentation and it throws errors so I wrote my own controller:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private fns: AngularFireFunctions) {}
 
  callMe() {
    console.log("Calling...");
    this.fns.httpsCallable('helloWorld');
  }
}
```

When I run `firebase emulators:start` I see an error message:

```
functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

It's objecting to these lines in `app.module.ts` and `app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppModule {}

export class AppComponent {}
```

Those aren't errors and the emulator recovers and starts up.

```
 ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000
```

I click the button in my HTML view, see `Calling...` in the console log, and nothing happens in the emulator log. I was expecting to see `Hello world` in the emulator logs. Why doesn't my Angular app call the Firebase Cloud Function?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [tutorial](https://github.com/tdkehoe/Firebase-Cloud-Functions-with-Angular/blob/main/README.md) that answers this question. Here's the `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

// AngularFire 7
// import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
// import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
// import { provideFunctions, getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from '@angular/fire/functions'; // https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#instrument_your_app_to_talk_to_the_emulators

// AngularFire 6
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
import { USE_EMULATOR } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions'; // comment out to run in the cloud

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    // AngularFire 7
    // provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    // provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    // provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),

    // AngularFire 6
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireFunctionsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: USE_EMULATOR, useValue: ['localhost', 5001] } // comment out to run in the cloud
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This uses AngularFire 6. I haven't been able to get AngularFire 7 to work with callable functions.

This runs the functions in the emulator. To run your functions in the cloud comment out two lines.

Here's `app.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// AngularFire 7
// import { getApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
// import { provideFunctions, getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator, httpsCallable } from '@angular/fire/functions'; // https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#instrument_your_app_to_talk_to_the_emulators
// import { Firestore, doc, getDoc, getDocs, collection, updateDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

// AngularFire 6
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  data$: any;

  constructor(private functions: AngularFireFunctions) {
    const callable = this.functions.httpsCallable('executeOnPageLoad');
    this.data$ = callable({ name: 'Charles Babbage' });
  }

  callMe() {
    console.log("Calling...");
    const callable = this.functions.httpsCallable('callMe');
    this.data$ = callable({ name: 'Ada Lovelace' });
  };
}
```

Again this AngularFire 6. The variable `data$` handles the data returned from the cloud function.

`httpsCallable` takes one parameter, the name of the function.

`callable` executes the function and takes one parameter, an object holding the data to send to the function.

The HTML view:

```html
<div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="basic" (click)='callMe()'>Call me!</button>
</div>

{{ data$ | async }}
```

The view show a button for the user the click and the data returned from the function.

And the `index.js` cloud functions:

```js
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and set up triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// executes on page load
exports.executeOnPageLoad = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log("The page is loaded!")
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.name);
    // console.log(context);
    return 22
});

// executes on user input
exports.callMe = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log("Thanks for calling!")
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.name);
    // console.log(context);
    return 57
});
```

Each functions uses `https.onCall((data, context) => {}` to make it a callable function, i.e., callable from Angular. `data` is the data sent from Angular. `context` is metadata about the execution of the function. Each function returns data, which is displayed in the HTML view.

To run the functions use the emulator:

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not define a **callable** function: `functions.https.onRequest`. It instead defines a regular HTTP function, which you can invoke with something like `fetch`.

Callable Cloud Functions are defined with `functions.https.onCall`. To implement a **callable** function, have a look at the documentation on [writing a callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function).

---

In addition this code does not invoke the function yet, but instead merely looks it up:

```
this.fns.httpsCallable('helloWorld');
```

To invoke it, you'll need to invoke it with some extra parenthesis, or store it in a variable and then invoke it as shown in the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md#creating-a-callable-function).

```
const callable = fns.httpsCallable('my-fn-name');
this.data$ = callable({ name: 'some-data' });
```

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote the function to
`exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {`
The error message about `export` is gone, I now see that it was complaining about `export` in the cloud function, not in the Angular app. The emulator now says `Loaded functions definitions from source: helloWorld.` so the emulator is hooked up to the cloud function. But clicking the button in the Angular view doesn't result in "Hello word!" in the emulator logs. Did I do something wrong with AngularFire in the controller?

Comment: You're not invoking the function as far as I can see. See the second part of my updated answer.

Comment: I'm not getting anything in the emulator logs. I put some extra parentheses onto `helloWorld()`:

`this.functions.httpsCallable('helloWorld()');`

That didn't work. 

The code provided in the AngularFire documentation throws errors. 

"template: `{ data$  | async }`" throws `Unexpected character EOF`. 

`fns.httpsCallable('helloWorld')` needs to be `this.fns.httpsCallable('helloWorld')`. 

`this.data$` throws an error `Unexpected token` because `data$` was never defined. 

`callable({ name: 'some-data' })` throws an error `Cannot find name 'callable'`.

Comment: This doesn't work either:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public functions: AngularFireFunctions) { }

  answer: any;

  callMe() {
    console.log("Calling...");
    this.answer = this.functions.httpsCallable('helloWorld');
  };
}
```

Comment: The `()` shouldn't be in the string that you pass to declare or load the callable. That makes no sense, as it would look for a function with that name. Instead, you should invoke the symbol you get back from the lookup by adding `()`, as shown in the documentation an in my answer. I highly recommend storing the symbol in a variable as shown there, and then invoking it with `thatSymbol()`.

Comment: These comments are getting too long so I've opened a new question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74046762/how-to-call-firebase-cloud-functions-with-angularfire-6-and-7 

I appreciate all your help.